# Getting Running Total of Time column using T-SQL in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I have a table XYZ with employee login duration details in TIME datatype column.

```
    EmployeeID | DomainID | LoginDuration
----------------------------------------------------------------
      1111         12       02:32:55:0000000
      1111          4       00:57:17.0000000
      1111         12       01:06:25.0000000
      1111         11       03:31:23.0000000
      2222         11       02:42:17.0000000
      2222          4       03:54:52.0000000
      2222         10       04:08:29.0000000
```

Apart from the above columns, I also have `LoginTimeStamp` and `LoginWeek` columns, which I am using in a JOIN statement.

I am trying to obtain running totals for the `LoginDuration` Column as follows:

```
   EmployeeID | DomainID | HoursBefore      | LoginDuration     | HoursAfter | 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1111         12      00:00:00.0000000  02:32:55:0000000    **00:00:00.0000000**
      1111          4      02:32:55.0000000  00:57:17.0000000    03:30:12.0000000
      1111         12      03:30:12.0000000  01:06:25.0000000    04:36:37.0000000
      1111         11      04:36:37.0000000  03:31:23.0000000    08:08:00.0000000
      2222         11      00:00:00.0000000  02:42:17.0000000    **00:00:00.0000000**
      2222          4      01:32:31.0000000  03:54:52.0000000    04:14:48.0000000
      2222         10      04:14:48.0000000  04:08:29.0000000    08:09:40.0000000
```

HoursBefore is Previous Value of HoursAfter(00:00:00 for first row of each employee)

HoursAfter = HoursBefore+LoginDuration

For this purpose,I wrote the below query, But I am getting an error with the `HoursAfter` Column. It is not adding up the current value and previous value for each employee.

```
SELECT
    a.EmployeeID,a.LoginDuration,
    COALESCE(CAST(
        DATEADD(ms,
            SUM(DATEDIFF(ms,0,CAST(b.LoginDuration as datetime)))
            , 0)
        as time)
        ,'00:00:00') AS HoursBefore,
    a.LoginDuration as Hours,
    COALESCE(CAST(
        DATEADD(ms,
            SUM(DATEDIFF(ms,0,CAST(b.LoginDuration as datetime)))
            , a.Loginduration)
        as time)
        ,'00:00:00') As HoursAfter
FROM XYZ AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN XYZ AS b
ON (a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID) 
  AND (a.LoginWeek = b.LoginWeek)
  AND (b.LoginTimeStamp < a.LoginTimeStamp)
GROUP BY a.EmployeeID, a.LoginTimeStamp,a.LoginDuration
ORDER BY a.LoginWeek, a.EmployeeID, a.LoginTimeStamp;
```

I need help with the query such that the `HoursAfter` column for each employee is appropriate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
(This is my first query, reply if you may need any further details.)

Thanks.

Comment: What does hours before and hours after stand for??

Comment: pasting DDL,DML for queries is so easy.Look at this Addin:https://github.com/nycdotnet/TSqlFlex..

Comment: Hello Ivan,
HoursBefore is Previous Value of HoursAfter(00:00:00 for first row of each employee)
HoursAfter = HoursBefore+LoginDuration

Answer (score 0):

Pity SQL Server doesn't support period datatype yet, it would make the math so much simpler.

However, it dos have rather good support for window functions in newer versions, which we can use to solve this:

```
declare @t table (ID int, EmployeeID int, DomainID int, LoginDuration time)

insert @t
values
(1, 1111,         12,       '02:32:55.0000000'),
(2, 1111,          4,       '00:57:17.0000000'),
(3, 1111,         12,       '01:06:25.0000000'),
(4, 1111,         11,       '03:31:23.0000000'),
(5, 2222,         11,       '02:42:17.0000000'),
(6, 2222,          4,       '03:54:52.0000000'),
(7, 2222,         10,       '04:08:29.0000000')

;with x as (
    select *, dateadd(second, sum(datediff(second, 0, loginduration)) over (partition by employeeid order by id), 0) sum_duration_sec,
        row_number() over (partition by employeeid order by id) rn
    from @t
)
select 
    employeeid, 
    domainid, 
    convert(time, isnull(lag(sum_duration_sec) over (partition by employeeid order by id),0)) hoursbefore,
    loginduration, 
    convert(time, case when rn = 1 then 0 else sum_duration_sec end) hoursafter
from x
```

I introduced the ID column for brevity to establish the sequence, you'd probably want to use the (LoginWeek, LoginTimestamp) to order by.

Also, not sure about the requirement that HoursAfter should be 0 in 1st and 5th row - if not, delete the row_number() thing altogether.

Answer (score -1):

use OUTER APPLY to calculate the Hours After. Hours Before is just Hours After subtracting current duration

```
SELECT  a.EmployeeID, a.DomainID,
        HoursBefore = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(SECOND, b.after_secs - DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, a.LoginDuration), 0)),
        a.LoginDuration,
        HoursAfter  = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(SECOND, b.after_secs, 0))
FROM    XYZ AS a
OUTER APPLY
(
        SELECT  after_secs  = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, x.LoginDuration))
        FROM    XYZ x
        WHERE   x.EmployeeID         = a.EmployeeID
        AND     x.LoginWeek          = a.LoginWeek
        AND     x.LoginTimeStamp    <= a.LoginTimeStamp
) b
```